# How to add custom CSS defined by some user input in Angular4?

Tags: html, css, angular

I want to give users of my application the possibility to set plain CSS styles and those style definitions should be applied immediately to some HTML elements.

For example, I have a textarea bound to a model in my component:

```html
<textarea #customCss></<textarea>
```

In the same component, I defined a HTML element and for that HTML element, I want to give the user the possibility to assign plain CSS and allow the user to immediately preview the styled element. So basically, I would expect something like the following (which isn't working since the style property is readonly):

```html
<div style="{{ customCss.value }}">CUSTOM STYLED DIV</div>
```

Therefore, when a user enters `background:black;color:red;` in the textarea, I would expect that the HTML for the styled element would be rendered as:

```html
<div style="background:black;color:red;">CUSTOM STYLED DIV</div>
```

I don't see any chance to use the ng-style directive here directly since it would expect some JSON code and not plain CSS code.

So how can I tackle this problem in Angular4?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Niles advice got me back on the right track, thanks for that.

I already tried `[attr.style]="..."` before but without success but the problem was that the resulting CSS rendered to "unsafe" (at least in Safari), see [this](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/8491#issuecomment-217467582) Github issue.

Therefore, I wrote my own Pipe using the DomSanitizer in order to get this work. Here is the code:

```js
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Pipe({name: 'safeStyle'})
export class SafeStylePipe implements PipeTransform {
    constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {}

    transform(style) {
        return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustStyle(style);
    }
}
```

Our custom pipe can then be used as usual with:

```html
<div [attr.style]="customCss.value|safeStyle">CUSTOM STYLED DIV</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Probably the easiest way is to just bind to the attribute:

```
<div [attr.style]="customCss.value">CUSTOM STYLED DIV</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, that pointed me to the right direction, I posted the final solution.